# Proving a set has a lower bound

Tags: real-analysis, upper-lower-bounds

Is there a specific way to prove that a set has a lower bound (or an upper bound for that matter)?

A lot of the examples I see just end up stating that there exists a lower bound and I'm not really sure where that comes from... Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you have any example that you don't understand?

Comment: @AlexVong take the set S = { x € R : x > 0}

Comment: @AlexVong Its obvious to me that x = 0 is a lower bound but I don't really understand how to explicitly show it is

Comment: Consider $0\in\mathbb{R}$.  Let $x\in S$. Then $x \gt 0$ .  Thus $0\le x, \forall x \in S$

Comment: @RJM so by simply writing out that line I should be good right?

Comment: Depends on what your instructor thinks.

Comment: I think he's okay with what you just posted

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a set $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and real number $a \in \mathbb{R}$. To say "$a$ is a lower bound of $S$" is to say that $a \le s$ for all $s \in S$. To prove this, you show exactly that: start with an arbitrary $s \in S$, use the definition of membership of $S$, then via some logical path, prove that $a \le s$.

To take your example, take $S = \lbrace x > 0 : x \in \mathbb{R}\rbrace$, and $a = 0$. Note that this is indeed quite obvious, and the proof is going to rightfully feel like we are just stating the obvious!

Start by supposing $s \in S$. What does this tell us; what is the definition of $S$? This means that $s > 0$, which, by definition of $>$, means that $s \ge 0$ and $s \neq 0$. Therefore, $s \ge 0$. So, in total, we've shown that for all $s \in S$, we have the inequality $s \ge 0$, which is what we need to show a lower bound. Therefore $0$ is a lower bound for $S$.

How do you prove a lower bound exists? Often this just involves finding an explicit number that bounds your set below. Sometimes it's a non-constructive argument by contradiction, where a lower bound is assumed to exist, and a contradiction is reached (e.g. proving the boundedness of continuous functions). It's not always easy to extract a concrete lower bound from doing this.

Comment: Thank you! I guess I have just been doing simple examples and that is why I feel as if I am not proving anything

Answer (score 0):

Think about the definition of lower bound.
Suppose $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ and let $\delta\in\mathbb{R}$

If $\delta$ is a lower bound of $A$, then $\forall x\in A, \delta \le x$

Prove that there is such a delta.

Comment: but how do I prove that there exists such a delta

Comment: Show that all elements of A are greater than or equal to it.  Sometimes proofs in texts will leave it to the read to see how that is so, but you can always rely on that definition.  It would be informative to take one example you are experiencing difficulty with and work out how the stated lower bound is less than or equal to all elements of the set.